# Word characters differ between spell files (E763)

Tags: vim, spell-checking

### Synopsis

I am having trouble resolving Vim error E763: *Word characters differ between spell files*.

### Details

My `.vimrc` includes multiple spell languages:

```
set spelllang=en,de,pt,fr
```

When running Vim for the first time, it prompts for downloading the missing spell files and puts them into `.vim/spell`. With my above configuration, this results in the three files `de.utf-8.spl`, `fr.utf-8.spl`, and `pt.utf-8.spl`. (The english one ships with the Vim package.)

The documentation for E763 mentions:

> Vim allows you to use spell checking for several languages in the same file.
>   You can list them in the 'spelllang' option.  As a consequence all spell files
>   for the same encoding must use the same word characters, otherwise they can't
>   be combined without errors.  If you get a warning that the word tables differ
>   you may need to generate the .spl file again with :mkspell.  Check the FOL,
>   LOW and UPP lines in the used .aff file.
>
> The XX.ascii.spl spell file generated with the "-ascii" argument will not
>   contain the table with characters, so that it can be combine with spell files
>   for any encoding.  The .add.spl files also do not contain the table.

It seems that I need to regenerate the word tables, but the steps to do so do not follow directly from the manual. How shall I proceed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. I resolved it by asking the experts on the *vim_dev* mailing list.

The solution, straight from the horse's mouth:

> Try replacing the en_gb spell file that you installed long ago with
>   one downloaded from the server now.  The files on the site have been
>   updated some time ago to fix a mistake.
>
> Unfortunately there is no "update runtime files" command yet.

You can find the full thread [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/vim_dev/7HTs6kIKnPQ/discussion).

Comment: Yeah, just removing all `*.{spl,sug}` files that came with the vim package fixed the issue. It triggered of course downloading those `en*` files again, but thereafter no more bugging.